# I'm having problems registering the `category` scale in react-chart-js2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm using `react-chartjs-2` (5.2.0) and `chart.js` (4.3.0).

I have the following React component, to show some data in a bar chart (which is basically just a copy of the [Vertical Bar Chart `react-chartjs-2` example](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/examples/vertical-bar-chart/)):

```
import React from "react"
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2"
import { BarElement, CategoryScale, Chart, Legend, LinearScale, Title, Tooltip } from "chart.js"

Chart.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend)

export default function Test() {
    const options = {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: { position: 'top' },
            title: { display: true, text: 'A title' },
        },
    }

    const labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];

    const data = {
        labels,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                data: labels.map(() => Math.random()),
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
            },
            {
                label: 'Dataset 2',
                data: labels.map(() => Math.random()),
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)',
            },
        ],
    }

    return <Bar options={options} data={data}/>
}
```

I'm not sure why, I keep on getting the following two errors: `"category" is not a registered scale` and `Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID '' can be reused.`

For the first error, from what I read online the line `Chart.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend)` should register the `category` scale, so I'm not sure why I get the error anyways.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What you showed here seems perfect. I think you have some sort of (react?) error somewhere else in your code. Somehow there are two chart instances created for the same canvas element. Please add a codesandbox or stackblitz with a running version of the relevant part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to also install `chart.js` and include this two line in your js file:

```
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";
import { CategoryScale } from "chart.js";
```

command to install:

```
npm install chart.js
```

Comment: I already have `chart.js` installed. I tried changing the import source from `"chart.js"` to `"chart.js/auto"` already and it didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Importing `registerables` as follows solved the issue for me, it might be the same for you :

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(...registerables);
```